# PHP slice range by keys not by index

Tags: php, arrays, range, intervals

I have an array that looks like below:

```php
$array = [
  1000 => 'something',
  2000 => 'something',
  10000 => 'something',
  20000 => 'something',
  300000 => 'something',
];
```

Let's say I want to get an interval between `2000` and `20000`. Do I need to loop or is there a better way?

It's not an index so I can't use slice in this case.

### What I'm hoping for

I could do this myself with a loop, but hopefully there is something more clever.

```php
$range = getRange(2000, 20000, $array);
print_r($range);
```

#### Output

```
$range = [
  2000 => 'something',
  10000 => 'something',
  20000 => 'something',
];
```

Comment: Do you want to get only values?

Comment: @OsmanOmar No, an array, like the output above.

Comment: `array_filter` can filter based on the value or the key …

Comment: Loop is the correct way to handle it. You can use any wrapper like array_filter as suggested but it loops too. So you can say using a wrapper is elegant but not cleverer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_filter` can filter based on the value *or* the key …

```
function getRange($min, $max, $array) {
  return array_filter($array, function($key) use ($min, $max) {
    return $key >= $min && $key <= $max;
  }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY ); // flag to pass the key into the callback function
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getRange($start,$end, $array){
  $dataArray= array();
  foreach($array as $key=>$value){

    if($key>=$start && $key<=$end){
       $dataArray[$key]= $value;
     }
  }
 return $dataArray; 
}
```

You will need to iterate over the array and do it manually. Even if there is any built-in function that will iterate over the result. In short, you will always need to go through the data set and you will always have a complexity of O(N).

Comment: I ended up using the solution from @04FS with array_filter. It requires no iteration, even if PHP makes the iteration internally.

Comment: no problem, `array_filter` performs iteration on the backend

Answer (score 0):

`array_splice` is the solution for this. But the problem with `array_splice` are keys will never be preserved. Check this out for the solution [array_splice preserving keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585502/array-splice-preserving-keys)

Comment: If you read documentation about `array_splice`, 4th parameter is not for boolean.

Comment: and even you put `true` in the 4th parameter, keys still will not preserved. I just tried.

Comment: There is no example (#3) in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: Ahhh I stand corrected. I was thinking of `array_slice`. With `array_slice` keys can be preserved with the 4th parameter.

Comment: ohhh that's why :D